# Find an element inside an array of objects if you know another value inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

i know my description is a little bit confusing but let me explain you:
I have an array of objects likes this:
`[{name: Alex, last: Huros}, {name: Mitsos, last: Mitsou},name: Bill, last: Hurosis ]`

I have a variable which value is `const name = Alex`. Now i want to find the last where the name=Alex. To be more specific i want to find the name = Alex with some way or generaaly given the name i want to find the last for this name. How to do this? I've tried array.forEach and find but didn't work the way i use it

Comment: Use `find`. `arr.find(o => o.name === 'Alex').last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `find` method, which returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided `callback` function. Otherwise **undefined** is returned.

```js
var array=[{"name": "Alex", "last": "Huros"}, {"name": "Mitsos", "last": "Mitsou"},{"name": "Bill", "last": "Hurosis" }]
console.log(array.find(function(person){
  return person.name=="Alex";
}).last);
```

Or simply use `arrow` functions.

```
var last = array.find(p => p.name === 'Alex').last;
```